# Unicode characters - JSP and Struts 2 with GET request in the form (submit)

Tags: jsp, unicode, struts2, character-encoding, get

Here I have a case where unicode characters were not working because they are sending from the form as a GET request. This case was working before with the right POST request in the form. Unfortunately, our application was with a problem in IE8 and, to solve it, we have to change the submit method. And now, the right codification for unicode characters are not working.

Could anyone help me with some tip?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a server configuration setting. This question is therefore unanswerable without knowing exact server make/version.

Comment: Hi, BalusC. I just saw your answer now. Thanks a lot.
I already had solved my problem. I am using Tomcat and found the solution here: http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding

We have to put URIEncoding="UTF-8" at the HTTP connector in server.xml, so the unicode encoding will work with get requests.

Comment: That was a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I assumed you would help me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here: [wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding) 
We have to put `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` at the HTTP connector in server.xml, so the unicode encoding will work with get requests.